# Character and background images are not getting displayed in game window

Tags: python, pygame

I have just started building games in python.After following different tutorials, I built this game from my own experiences.But when I run my code,it just pops a blank black window not displaying any character not even background.There is no problem with syntax.I know there is something wrong but I am not able to figure out what is that.Can you please help me solve this problem?

```
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer




screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.init()
mixer.music.load("music1.file.mp3")
mixer.music.play(-1)


background = pygame.image.load("direction.png")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("car.png")
carX = random.randint(0,800)
carY = random.randint(0,600)
carX_change = 4
carY_change = 40

bulletImg = pygame.image.load("shoot.png")
bulletX = 370
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 0

font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",32)


score_value = 0


over_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",64)

def show_score():
    score = font.render("Score: " + str(score_value) ,True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(score,(10,10))

def game_over():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER",True,(0,0,0))
    screen.blit(over_text,(200,250))

def bullet(x, y):
    screen.blit(bulletImg,(x,y))

def car(x,y):
    screen.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def collision():
    distance = carX-bulletX
    if distance <= 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False

running = False
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bulletY_change = 20

            if carY>= 440:
                carY = 2000

            carX += carX_change
            carY += carY_change
            if carX <= 0:
                carX = 0
            elif carX >= 736:
                carX = 0
                car(carX,carY)


            bulletX += bulletX_change
            bulletY += bulletY_change

            collision()
            if collision:
               explosionSound = mixer.Sound("music2.file.mp3")
               explosionSound.play()
               bulletY = 480

            if bulletY<= 0:
                bulletY = 480
                bullet(bulletX, bulletY)


                screen.fill((255,255,255))
                screen.blit(background(0,0))
        show_score()
        game_over()
        car(carX,carY)
        bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: All of your drawing code is only executed when an event is in the event queue. Note how it is part of the `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the scene and to update the display in the application loop rather than the event loop. The event loop is executed when an event occurs, bit the application loop is executed once per frame:

```py
running = False
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(background(0,0))
    show_score()
    car(carX,carY)
    bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```